# retriveing data using join in an sql query and reprenting it in jdbc template

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

**`REPOTRANSSMISSION`** TABLE column are

```
REPO_TRANSMISSION_ID,
G3_SESSION_ID,
CLIENT_NM,
ASSESSMENT_SESSION_ID,
PACKAGE_SESSION_ID,
TEST_SESSION_ID,
SCORE_SESSION_ID,
REPO_TRANSMISSION_STATE_CD,
REPO_TRANSMISSION_DATA_TX,
REPO_TRANSMISSION_LEVEL_CD,
CREATE_DT,
LAST_MODIFIED_DT.
```

here `REPO_TRANSMISSION_ID` is the primary key and  `REPO_TRANSMISSION_STATE_CD` is the foregin key

2nd table **`REPO_ TRANSSMISSION_REQ_LOG`** column are

```
REPO_TRANSMISSION_REQ_LOG_ID
REPO_TRANSMISSION_ID
REQUEST_TX
RESPONSE_TX
ERROR_TX
CREATE_DT
LAST_MODIFIED_DT
```

here `PK_REPO_TRANSMISSION_REQ_LOG` is the primary key, `REPO_TRANSMISSION_ID` is foregin key

3rd tables **`REPO TRANSSMISSION STATE`** column are

```
REPO_TRANSMISSION_STATE_CD
REPO_TRANSMISSION_STATE_DS
CREATE_DT
LAST_MODIFIED_DT
and 
REPO_TRANSSMISSION_STATE_CD values are TRANS_RESP,
RECON_REQ,
RECON_ERR,
RECON_RETRY,
RECON_RESP
```

here `PK_REPO_TRANSMISSION_STATE_cd` is the primary key

I have to retrieve the `repo_transsmission_Id` when the `repotransmission_state_cd` value is above 4 and I have to join the 1 st and 2nd table.

How I will write the sql query?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to see how a query would look like to give you the results you need?

It would be something like this:

```
SELECT tr.repo_transmission_id
  FROM REPOTRANSSMISSION tr
    JOIN REPO_TRANSSMISSION_REQ_LOG lg ON (tr.REPO_TRANSMISSION_ID = lg.REPO_TRANSMISSION_ID)
WHERE tr.REPO_TRANSMISSION_STATE_CD > 4;
```